# Can’t find a way to decode / Use the data I receive from Amadeus API call

Tags: swift, api, amadeus

I am new to Amadeus API, I can’t seem to figure out how to use the data I receive from the API Call. I can print out the data. Can someone guide me in the right direction? Or maybe show me the simplest way to use the data in my app?

I import Amadeus and make a Struct that conforms to codable.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var results = [Result]()
}
struct Result: Codable{
    struct price: Codable {
        let total: String
    }
    struct links: Codable {
        let flightDates: String
        let flightOffers: String
    }
    let type: String
    let origin: String
    let destination: String
    let departureDate: String
    let returnDate: String
    let price: price
    let links: links
}
```

Then I have a function that makes the API Call ->

```
func testFlightDestinations() {
     amadeus.shopping.flightDestinations.get(
        params: ["origin": "MAD", "departureDate": "2022-04-20", "duration": "5"], 
        onCompletion: {
            result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                print(response.data[0])
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Fail\(error)")
            }
        })
}
```

Now this work all fine, I am able to print out the response.data[0], but no matter how I try to decode it, I am not able to use this data… Can anyone with Amadeus experience help me?

Here is my latest version of decoding:

```
func testFlightDestinations() async {
     amadeus.shopping.flightDestinations.get(
        params: ["origin": "MAD", "departureDate": "2022-04-20", "duration": "5"], 
        onCompletion: {
            result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                print(response.data[0])
                
                let data = response.data
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do{
                    let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Response, from: response.data)
                    print(results[0].origin)
                } catch { 
                    print("error")
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Fail\(error)")
            }
        })
}
```

}

Sample JSON:

```
[{
"departureDate" : "2022-04-20",
"origin" : "MAD",
"links" : {
  "flightOffers" : "https:\/\/test.api.amadeus.com\/v2\/shopping\/flight-offers?originLocationCode=MAD&destinationLocationCode=PMI&departureDate=2022-04-20&returnDate=2022-04-25&adults=1&nonStop=false",
  "flightDates" : "https:\/\/test.api.amadeus.com\/v1\/shopping\/flight-dates?origin=MAD&destination=PMI&departureDate=2022-04-20&oneWay=false&duration=5&nonStop=false&viewBy=DURATION"
},
"destination" : "PMI",
"type" : "flight-destination",
"returnDate" : "2022-04-25",
"price" : {
  "total" : "46.39"
}
```

},

New struct from app.quicktype.io =

```
struct Result: Codable {
let type, returnDate, destination: String
let price: Price
let origin, departureDate: String
let links: Links
}

struct Links: Codable {
let flightOffers, flightDates: String
}

struct Price: Codable {
let total: String
}
```

From the README file in Amadeus SDK: ## Response

Responses are based on [swift
closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html), that
are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed around and used
in your code.

Every API call response is handled by the `OnCompletion` closure which returns
a [Result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) value that
represents either a success, which contains the `JSON` object, or a failure,
containing the error.

If the API call contained a JSON response, the SDK will parse that JSON into
`.result` attribute.  If it contains a `data` key, that is made available in
`.data` attribute. The raw body of the response is always available in `.body`
attribute.

Comment: Also, when I try to decode this, I get the error “Cannot convert Value of type “JSON” to expected argument type “Data”

Comment: Post your decoding code as well

Comment: Hi, I added decoding code now

Comment: Also 
1) it would be nice to have a look at a sample JSON of a Result object that you're trying to decode. 
2) it's `try decoder.decode(Response.self, ...`
3) Do you get your error in a catch block? make `print(error)` and post a complete error text here as well

Comment: 1: I will add the sample JSON now, 2: added .self, 3: no, I get the error in the “try decode.decoder”

Comment: Your json seems to be of type [Result] not of type Response.

Comment: If I don’t try to to decode, I can print out the json response, but when I try to decode, I always get this error: “cannot convert value of type “JSON” to expected argument type “Data””

Comment: What's `response.data[0]` output exactly? Also, what's thee definition of `flightDestinations.get(params:onCompletion:)`? Is it already parsed?

Comment: Respons.data[0] is: {
  "returnDate" : "2022-04-25",
  "price" : {
    "total" : "46.39"
  },
  "origin" : "MAD",
  "destination" : "PMI",
  "departureDate" : "2022-04-20",
  "type" : "flight-destination",
  "links" : {
    "flightOffers" : "https: Some URL",
    "flightDates" : "https: Some URL "
  }
}

Comment: flightDestinations.get(params:onCompletion:) is from the Amadeus SDK that I Imported, like I said, I am new to Amadeus so I’m not exactly sure

Comment: But you can still show its declaration, with `func get(...)` if you can call it...

Comment: Copy a complete Json response and use https://app.quicktype.io/ to create a Model. Add this to your question. Something about your model seems suspicious.

Comment: Could you mouse over `response` with `Alt` pressed, and tell us what's its type? Sample for `response.data`, something tells me it's already kind of parsed... And `print("error")` =< `print("error: \(error)")

Comment: Added the struct from app.QuickType.io

Comment: Mouse over get(...) with Alt + Ctrl, and click on it, you'll see the method definition, copy/paste it here, it's still unclear what's it's really doing...

Comment: I added the response from Amadeus README file in my question

Comment: I am on My IPad now (playgrounds 4) testing at work, will not be able to click Alt + Ctrl before I get home on my Mac

Comment: And what's `JSON`? That's a custom class, how is this defined? But seeing `The raw body of the response is always available in .body attribute.`, that `response.body` that you want to use with `JSONDecoder()`.

Comment: Solved! So.. I found out that Amadeus SDK also includes SwiftyJSON SDK, so when I found this out, it was easy. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

did you review this repository:
https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-code-examples

You could find several examples with Swift.